# How to let CompileAssemblyFromSource() refer to user defined types in calling program

Tags: vb.net, compileassemblyfromsource

I'm successfully using dynamically compiled assemblies to evaluate user definable expressions at run time. My question is about how to pass references to the types defined in my own program into the CompileAssemblyFromSource() function. Currently I'm forced to use 'object' in my user definable expressions, which causes late binding. As soon as I try to use my own types in the assembly code, I get 'Error BC30002 - Type 'cMyClass' is not defined'

I found the following to add to the parameters which sounds exactly right:

```
Dim executingAssembly As Assembly
Dim executingAssemblyName As String
executingAssembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()
executingAssemblyName = executingAssembly.Location
params.ReferencedAssemblies.Add(executingAssemblyName)
```

But this doesn't seem to help at all...

Here is a sample function I'm trying to compile unsuccessfully:

```
Public Class Sample
Public Shared Function StaticFunction(ByVal myObject As cMyClass) As String
Return myObject.DoSomething
End Function
End Class
```

If I replace 'cMyClass' with 'object' all is well.

Comment: Yes, that's the way to do it.  You cannot ignore the need to make the class Public and to use the proper namespace or Imports directive.

Comment: Hans, this is excellent. You immediately found my mistake. My classes are public, but I didn't think of adding a 'Imports myOwnProjectNameSpace' at the top of the expression. I think it works now!

Comment: Hans, thanks so much. You gave me the right answer. The expressions now run roughly double the speed of before. That's a big improvement for us.

Comment: Do you wan to file an answer for this yourself?

Comment: I'll pass.  Not so sure this is worth preserving.

Comment: OK, for me it was a problem, but I'm a noob. Thanks again!